# D7 Multiple multi value fields not showing correctly in views

Tags: drupal, view

I have a node type which contains a multiple value field, users can fill out multiple instances of this field. Looks something like this, where "error" is the multiple value field:

- Item

  - Description
  - Error

    - error type
    - error date

Some items have multiple error entries, like:

---

- Item A

  - Lorem ipsum
  - Error 1

    - type X
    - 01-01-2014
  - Error 2

    - type Y
    - 21-03-2014

---

- Item B

  - Lorem ipsum
  - Error 1

    - type X
    - 01-04-2014
  - Error 2

    - type Y
    - 11-05-2014

---

Now when I want to generate a table in views, it shows 4 rows (which is correct, 1 row for every Item + error), but the corresponding error type and date are wrong:

```
Item | description | Error type | Error date
A      Lorem ipsum    Type X      01-01-2014
A      Lorem ipsum    Type Y      01-01-2014
B      Lorem ipsum    Type X      01-04-2014
B      Lorem ipsum    Type Y      01-04-2014
```

I tried using the aggregation option and group by entity ID, but then I end up with 2 rows (item A and B).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

After rigorous testing I found out I was using the wrong module for multivalue field groups. If you want to achieve the above, use the [field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) module. Then create a relationship in views to the field containing the field collection, et voila, you can output all subvalues in seperate rows.